# JSON parser returns Null

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I am trying to learn how to parse JSON data so I can handle big databases. I wrote code to login into a website.

I have following JSON data from a successful login request:

```
JSON string : correct username and password [{"user_id":"7","first_name":"dada","last_name":"Kara","e_mail":"yaka@gmail","fullname":"Dada Kara","forum_username":"ycan"}]
```

and i use following code to parse but it doesnt parse it

```
-(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender{

    NSString *username = usernameTextfield.text; 
    NSString *password = passwordTextfield.text;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kPostUrl]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"e_mail=%@&password=%@", username, password];
    [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    //NSString *responseStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
    //NSLog(@"Response : %@", responseStr);

    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSON string : %@", json_string);

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *responseObj = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
    NSArray *name = [responseObj objectForKey:@"first_name"];

    NSLog(@"Name : %@", name);
}
```

The result from my `NSLog` for name is `NULL`

Where is the problem and how can I parse such a data so when it comes to lots of rows I can save it to the local FMDB database on iphone

**------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------**

Actual problem was response JSON string from server included echo beginning of the string,json parser only parses between double quotes "", so all i just needed to trim echo from string and parse new string.

and bingo!

```
//trim in coming echo
    NSString *newString1 = [json_string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"correct username and password\n" withString:@""];



    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSArray *responseObj = [parser objectWithString:newString1 error:nil];

    NSDictionary *dataDict = [responseObj objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *userID = [dataDict objectForKey:@"user_id"];

    NSLog(@"user_id: %@", userID);
```

output : user_id : 7

Comment: The JSON string is an array that contains dictionary, so first extract the dictionary and then parse it.

Comment: i guess below answer is the one you have mentioned but i still get NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

 NSArray *responseObj = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

NSDictionary *dataDict = [responseObj objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *name = [dataDict objectForKey:@"first_name"];
```

Did you print recieve data ? is it showing recieve data from server ? If yes then try with different encoding.

Comment: yes `NSLog(@"JSON string : %@", json_string);` prints `JSON string : correct username and password [{"user_id":"7","first_name":"dada","last_name":"Kara","e_mail":"yaka@gmail","fullname":"Dada Kara","forum_username":"ycan"}]
` what do u mean by different encoding?

Comment: NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:Some other encoding]; like NSASCIIStringEncoding & other

Comment: problem is my json string begins with correct username and password  while a json parser only parses between double quotes "" i need to find a way that parser starts after string correct user name and password

Comment: You can create your own string with the Help of Nsstring append format and Then send it to Parser.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm. I was finding solution for this problem from hours. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like Objectify ($15 US) or JSON Accelerator ($0.99 US) in the Mac App store to automatically generate data models for you that would make the model as simple as doing object.firstName.